# El iframe de suscripciones en Mobile no se ve correctamente

Tags: iframe

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]Necesito corregir la visualización del iframe para completar los datos de pago de una suscripción.

Se ve así:

[image: Ventana de suscripción]

[image: Corregida la visualización pero no me deja scrollear]

Comment: Ernesto, puedes ser mas especifico sobre que se ve mal?

Comment: Hola Einer! La imagen que subí es tal cual como se ve en mobile, no te permite hacer scroll siquiera ni completar los datos para poder finalizar la compra.

Comment: Intenta dejando la consola con la configuracion de la ventana pequeña abierta, refrescar la pagina y dinos si se acomodo. Hay veces que el css no se acomoda cuando se redimensiona la pagina sin refrescar el navegador.

Comment: En Desktop se ve perfecto, el problema es solo en mobile por eso el ejemplo lo subo con la ventana de mobile

Comment: En tu ejemplo veo que utilizaste la consola de chrome para redimensionar la pagina utilizando la herramienta de dispositivos. O no?

Comment: Si, hice eso. Ahí subí una captura de como se ve desde un iphone 7

Comment: primero que nada no podemos hacer nada con las imagenes ... segundo agrega código que tienes para darle estilo a ese modal, tercero el iframe debe estar al 100% o menos de su contenedor, si su contenedor se dale de la pantalla el iframe tambien...

Answer (score 1):

Puedes usar la [media querys](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/CSS/Media_queries) para ajustar el tamaño del elemento dependiendo de la pantalla.

Si estas usando [bootstrap](http://getbootstrap.com/) te recomiendo que hechas un vistazo al sistema de [Grid](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/3.3/examples/grid/) que tiene. Es muy sencillo de usar y es Responsibe con practicamente todos los dispositivos.

Instenta darle un ancho y alto fijo dependiendo del tañaño de la pantalla, o bien al `iframe` o al `div` contenedor de este.

Comment: Gracias, pruebo esto y les cuento

Comment: Hola! Gracias por tu ayuda, logré que se visualice correctamente, acabo de subir la imagen al posteo. El problema que tengo ahora es que no me deja hacer scroll para poder completar la totalidad de los campos. Cuando scrolleo se mueve el fondo y no el iframe.

Comment: Utiliza el atributo `overflow` dandole el valor `auto` o `hidden`, conforme mejor se adecúe a tu documento. Utilizalo sobre el div qque contiene el iframe

Comment: @Ernesto te importaria dar como válida la respuesta? así me darias el logro de profesor :-)
Tampoco me ha quedado claro si has conseguido solucionarlo